# Keyboard warning in Xcode Simulator

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator

I have recently started getting this warning in Xcode when working in `Simulator` mode. Apple were not able to help and suggested I submit a bug report, which I have done. But I wondered if anyone here has experienced the same?

It occurs when the keyboard is used during `Simulator` mode only. The screen freezes for a few seconds and then carries on. Very frustrating.

```
-[UIKeyboardInputManagerClient handleError:forRequest:] will retry sending handleKeyboardInput:keyboardState:completionHandler: to keyboard daemon after receiving Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4097 "connection to service named com.apple.TextInput" UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=connection to service named com.apple.TextInput}
```

Comment: I have the same issue, don't know how to solve so far (the app works fine on iPhone, but in Simulator the its almost impossible to type anything)

Comment: Are you using textViewDidBeginEditing or similar?

Comment: What version of Xcode and iOS are you using here?

Comment: I am using Xcode 8.2.1